# Template parse errors when use NgbCarousel with ngFor

Tags: ng-bootstrap

I want use ngb-carousel with ngFor,My code like this:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4VgT.png)

but this make some error like this:

```
<ngb-carousel>
  <template  ngFor let-home [ngForOf]="homes | async" >
    <ngbSlide [home]="home">
      <img src="{{item.thumb}}" alt="Random first slide">
    </ngbSlide>
  </template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

home.component.html?c8ce:1 Error: Template parse errors:(…)

who can give me a example use ngb-carousel with ngFor?

Comment: Please provide code to accompany your question :-)

Comment: <ngb-carousel>
    <template  ngFor let-home [ngForOf]="homes | async" >
    <ngbSlide [home]="home">
    <img src="{{item.thumb}}" alt="Random first slide">
    </ngbSlide>
    </template>
    </ngb-carousel>

Comment: Sorry, for some reason that code was present in your question but was not being displayed. I've edited your question to display it correctly.

Comment: The code has been displayed now.

Answer (score 6):

The syntax for ng-bootstrap slides is `<template ngbSlide>` and we don't have the `<ngbSlide>` element / component hence the parsing error. What you should be doing instead is to have `ngFor` generate `<template ngbSlide>` like so:

```
<ngb-carousel>
  <template *ngFor="let imgIdx of [1, 2, 3]" ngbSlide>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/500?r={{imgIdx}}" alt="Random slide no {{imgIdx}}">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>slide label no {{imgIdx}}</h3>
      <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
    </div>
  </template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

Here is a working plunker showing this in action: http://plnkr.co/edit/FXx9Q0UO14sp0RqbPnVh?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This might be a late answer, but if your the images from your database or anywhere for that matter is an Array. So you can iterate through them using `NgFor` on the HTML.

**carousel.component.html**

```
<ngb-carousel *ngIf="images!=null">
   <div *ngFor="let image of images">
      <ng-template ngbSlide>
        <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
           <img src="{{image}}" alt="image">
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </div>
</ngb-carousel>
```

The `ngfor` will create `ng-template` equal to the length of the array.

**carousel.component.ts**

```
images = ['image1', 'image2', 'image3'];
```

Comment: Just tried to make it work, and it took me a while to figure out that it doesn't work (anymore) when the ng-template is wrapped in a div.